# Source code for playing ten songs one by one in background in ios?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

i am new to ios.I am doing a project.In that project i want to implement 10 songs play one one in background and also it contains forward and backward buttons.When we click on forward button songs are played from next songon onwards and similarly for backbutton also.

Please send me the code,

Comment: This is not a "give me the code" website. This is for asking for help with specific programming questions.

Answer (score 3):

I Recommend Reading all about AVAudioPlayer in the apple docs

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Here is some sample code, though it doesnt have your complete implementation, sure you can work it out though.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2

There is a full sample project using AVAudioPlayer here 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008636